# Configuring screen in QNX, drm-intel crashes

Tags: qemu, intel-graphics, qnx

I'm building QNX OS (BSP 7.0 x86_64) and I have a working image. I'm running it over a qemu emulated enviroment.

Qemu virtual machine runs in a Windows host and is invoked as follows:

```
./qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 1G -smp 4
 -hda QNX.img 
-realtime mlock=off -vga std -sdl
-nic tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,model=e1000,script=no,downscript=no
```

Once started I run:

```
export GRAPHICS_ROOT=/usr/lib/graphics/intel-drm
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(getconf _CS_LIBPATH):$GRAPHICS_ROOT
```

With valid environment variables, I launch intel-drm. No logs are generated so seems it is working properly.

```
 pidin | grep drm-intel
  430102   1 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r SIGWAITINFO
  430102   2 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r CONDVAR     (0x8452bb0)
  430102   3 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r CONDVAR     (0x824cefc)
  430102   4 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r RECEIVE     1
  430102   5 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r RECEIVE     1
  430102   6 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r RECEIVE     1
  462873   1 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r SIGWAITINFO
  462873   2 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r CONDVAR     (0x8452bb0)
  462873   3 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r CONDVAR     (0x824cefc)
  462873   4 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r RECEIVE     1
  462873   5 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r RECEIVE     1
  462873   6 _64/sbin/drm-intel  10r RECEIVE     1
```

The problem comes when trying to launch drm-probe-displays. Just after execution it crashes and makes intel-drm crash.

```
Process 577558 (drm-intel) terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 ip=000000000809057f(/x86_64/sbin/drm-intel@main+0x000000000003181f) mapaddr=000000000004857f. ref=0000000000000028
Please run drm server first!
# Jun 16 10:07:54.049                       dumper.4                 slog      0  run fault pid 577558 tid 4 signal 11 code 1 ip 0x809057f x86_64/sbin/drm-intel
Jun 16 10:07:54.050                       dumper.4                 slog      0  pid 577558 core file created at /tmp/drm-intel.core
```

There isn't more information about the crash. By checking pci-tool, I'm able to see that the device vendorID/deviceID are not intel specifics.

**Could be the error produced by this device?**

**If it is the case, does anyone knows how can I emulate intel graphics on qemu?**

B000:D02:F00 @ idx 4
vid/did: 1234/1111
Technical Corp, <device id - unknown>
class/subclass/reg: 03/00/00
PC Compatible VGA Display Controller

**Any clue about what could be the root cause?**

Comment: About Intel graphics emulation, in Qemu 3.1.0 on Debian, available graphic cards are: cirrus, std vga, vmware, QXL paravirtual, tcx (sun4m only) Sun TCX framebuffer, cg3 (sun4m only) Sun cgthree framebuffer, virtio and none. From the man page.

Comment: @dezque Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. Finally I manage to get a machine that copies the production environment. However If you have any solution, I'm still interesting on it.